# Can a service principal (Azure Application multi-tenant) grant admin consent to application in tenant using AZ CLI?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-cli

## Context

We are using multiple directories (**TENANT_A**, **TENANT_B**) on Azure. The goal is to create a service principal (Application), **_SP_APP**, inside **TENANT_A** which is granted access into **TENANT_B**. We want to use this service principal in script to manage both directory easily.
One of the script is to make new Application Registration inside **TENANT_B** AND to grant *ADMIN CONSENT* for these applications.

### What is done

#### _SP_APP

- Global Admin on both Directory
- Granted Access to **TENANT_B** (Visible in Enterprise Application)
- Api Permissions were granted Admin Consent (**TENANT_A** and **TENANT_B**)

  - Microsoft Graph (Delegated and Application Full Access)
  - Azure Active Directory Graph (Delegated and Application Full Access)

## Steps

### Working correctly

```
# Login with service principal of multiple tenants application
az login --service-principal -u _SP_APP -p <PASSWORD> --tenant TENANT_B
# Creating application and fetching ID
_OBJECT_ID=`az ad app create ...`
```

### Not Working

```
# Granting Admin Consent
az ad app permission admin-consent --id $_OBJECT_ID
# ERROR
Bad Request({"ClassName":"Microsoft.Portal.Framework.Exceptions.ClientException","Message":"AADSTS50058: A silent sign-in request was sent but no user is signed in.\r\nTrace ID: 9c9bd004-a97a-4543-8ff0-e314de77a700\r\nCorrelation ID: 44c79409-2f3e-43de-a84b-1e5a42e382e7\r\nTimestamp: 2019-10-28 15:54:20Z" ...
```

What is strange is that when we `az login` with a Global Admin User and execute the script, it works fine.

## Question

Did we miss something to allow this service principal to be able to grant admin-consent or is it something only "user" can do? (I did not find any response in microsoft azure documentation).

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have confirmed with Azure support engineer. We can not use service principal to grant admin-consent.

If you must use service principal to do this, you can use Microsoft Graph api. It will consent permissions automatically.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/xx.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2PermissionGrants

{
  "clientId": "clientId-value",
  "consentType": "consentType-value",
  "expiryTime": "2016-10-19T10:37:00Z",
  "id": "id-value",
  "principalId": "principalId-value",
  "resourceId": "resourceId-value"
}
```

To call this api, you need to provide an access token, refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service) for more details.

Comment: Thank you @tony-ju, we just tried this. It does not respond exactly to our case.
This endpoint seems to only grant access to "Delegated" permissions which do not require "Admin Consent".
For those whom want to grant consent to these kind of permissions, some precisions:
clientId = ObjectId of service principal of the application to grant access to.
resourceId = Resource application's service principal Id (Microsoft Graph, Windows Azure Active Directory), you can see them if you click on a permission of a service principal in the details

Comment: It seems there is a need for a scope field, there was some error if we did not put one. The documentation is [there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/oauth2permissiongrant?view=graph-rest-beta) for whose who wants.

Comment: For now, we are still searching a solution to our specific case but we will accept this as it responds to most case. Thanks.
We will update the solution if we find a way.